# How to use @Size validation while using Float field with javax library?

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator

I am trying to use maximum size validation with `Float` datatype with javax validations. Here is example

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 5, max = 10)
public Float getPhone(){

}
```

But I am getting error that I can't use Size validation with Float datatype. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

`@Size` does not work with Float types. To quote the javadocs of the constraint:

```
/**
 * The annotated element size must be between the specified boundaries (included).
 * <p/>
 * Supported types are:
 * <ul>
 *     <li>{@code CharSequence} (length of character sequence is evaluated)</li>
 *     <li>{@code Collection} (collection size is evaluated)</li>
 *     <li>{@code Map} (map size is evaluated)</li>
 *     <li>Array (array length is evaluated)</li>
 * </ul>
 * <p/>
 * {@code null} elements are considered valid.
 *
 */
```

so this constraints is really about the size of a string or collection. You could write your own validator for float and register via xml - see http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#xml-mapping-constraintdefinition

However, I recommend against it, since it does not make sense to speak about "size" in the context you want to use it.

You could use `@Min` and `@Max`, but not all providers support the float data type, due to the problem of rounding.

Looking at your example, it seems you want to store a phone number. Why would you ever choose a float for that to begin with?

Comment: Thanks @Hardy. I know that for storing phone number I should not use float datatype. But I am working on a system where database design is not done by me. and there is `decimal(10,0)` datatype for phone num in db. Now I generated my beans from java code. (Dynamically from Database). So it is float mapping with decimal (in db). Any solution for this?

Comment: Which datatype if preferable for phone num? even Double will also not suppose @size validation.

Comment: If the database column is of type decimal, your Java property should be of type [java.math.BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).  Both SQL decimal and java.math.BigDecimal represent a number as a sequence of digits, while float and double are "inexact" because they represent a number as a m×2ⁿ.